# D3.js: How to get the computed width and height for an arbitrary element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to know exactly the width and height for an arbitrary `g` element in my `SVG` because I need to draw a selection marker around it once the user has clicked it.

What I've seen in the internet is something like: `d3.select("myG").style("width")`. The problem is that the element will not always have an explicit width attribute set. For instance, when I create a circle inside the `g`, it will have the radious (`r`) set instead of the width. Even if I use the `window.getComputedStyle` method on a `circle`, it will return "auto".

Is there a way to calculate the width of an arbitrary `svg` selement in `D3`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

## For SVG elements

Using something like `selection.node().getBBox()` you get values like

```
{
    height: 5, 
    width: 5, 
    y: 50, 
    x: 20
}
```

## For HTML elements

Use `selection.node().getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: For HTML elements, use `getBoundingClientRect()` instead of the SVG-only `getBBox()`. Like so: `d3.select("body").node().getBoundingClientRect().width`

Comment: Could do with a little more info to help. For SVG or or HTML elements? Is it only Firefox which is the issue? Is anything reported in the console? What is the returned value? Do you have a minimal code example (jsfiddle) which demonstrated the problem?

Answer (score 41):

> **.getBoundingClientRect()** returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.We can easily get following

- left, right
- top, bottom
- height, width

**Example :**

```
var element = d3.select('.elementClassName').node();
element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

Comment: Still works as of D3 V6, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Once I faced with the issue when I did not know which the element currently stored in my variable (svg or html) but I needed to get it width and height. I created this function and want to share it:

```
function computeDimensions(selection) {
  var dimensions = null;
  var node = selection.node();

  if (node instanceof SVGGraphicsElement) { // check if node is svg element
    dimensions = node.getBBox();
  } else { // else is html element
    dimensions = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  }
  console.log(dimensions);
  return dimensions;
}
```

Little demo in the hidden snippet below. We handle click on the blue div and on the red svg circle with the same function.

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', 50)
  .attr('height', 50);

function computeDimensions(selection) {
    var dimensions = null;
  var node = selection.node();

  if (node instanceof SVGElement) {
    dimensions = node.getBBox();
  } else {
    dimensions = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  }
  console.clear();
  console.log(dimensions);
  return dimensions;
}

var circle = svg
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("cx", 30)
    .attr("cy", 30)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .on("click", function() { computeDimensions(circle); });
    
var div = d3.selectAll("div").on("click", function() { computeDimensions(div) });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffd;
}

.div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Click on blue div block or svg circle
</h3>
<svg></svg>
<div class="div"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use even less code by just calling clientWidth directly:

```
const element = d3.select('yourElementIdOrClass');

const width = element.node().clientWidth;
```