# How can I get the heights of each in a group of generated D3.js elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom, svg

My question is an extension of this question:
[D3.js: How to get the computed width and height for an arbitrary element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990857/d3-js-how-to-get-the-computed-width-and-height-for-an-arbitrary-element)

In my case however, I want to get the computed height of a **group** of elements created by D3.

The items in the group are created as follows:

```
const boxGroup = mainArea.selectAll('.boxes-user')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr('id', (d) => 'bars-user-' + d[0].userId )
  .attr("transform", (d) => {
    currentRow = currentRow + 1;
    return "translate( 0, " + ((rowHeight * currentRow) + (20 * currentRow)) + ")"
  });
```

This creates multiple `<g>` elements. One for each item in the `data` array.

I would like to be able to determine the computed eventual height of each generated `.boxes-user` group.

**Is this possible? If yes, how?**

Comment: if you are getting this information after the element has been loaded into the DOM you could use `document.getElementById('your-elemet-id').getBoundingClientRect().height` also this package might be of interest https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-properties

Comment: I want it to be part of the D3 code, since I want to use this information to position other elements

Comment: Using a global variable `currentRow` inside the callback is very bad practice. you have the `(d,i) => { ... }` to get the index

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks I will fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Computing width and height for `<g>` elements is exactly the same way i.e. using `getBBox()`. As the referred link doesn't provide an example, here's one console logging the heights of the `<g>` elements containing random elements.

```js
var data = [{type: 'text',value: "Test1"}, {type: 'rect', value: {w: 40, h: 70}}, {type: 'circle', value: {r: 12, x: 120}}];

const boxGroup = d3.select('svg').selectAll('.boxes-user')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g").classed('boxes-user', true)
  .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    return "translate(" + (i * 100) + ", 30)";
  }).each(function (d) {
  if(d.type === 'circle') {
     d3.select(this).append('circle').style('fill', d.value.color || 'steelblue')
         .attr('r', d.value.r || 10).attr('cx', d.value.x || 20);
    } else if(d.type === 'rect') {
    d3.select(this).append('rect').attr('width', d.value.w || 40).attr('height', d.value.h || 20);   
    } else {
     d3.select(this).append('text').text(d.value);
    }    
    // "this" is the group element here. Computing height for the same
    console.log('height of ' + d.type + ': ' + d3.select(this).node().getBBox().height);
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg width="700" height="500"></svg>
```

Make sure the elements within it are added before you compute the dimensions or else it'd end up resulting into 0. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: This is an elaborate hard coding way creating elements by type, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39288730/9938317 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51860323/9938317

Comment: I know but the motto here was to clear up that `getBBox()` works for `<g>` elements as well. Thanks rio.