# How do I get the width of an svg element which has a percentage using d3js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts, width

I tried to stretch a chart to the dimension of a div-father but i actually can't take the dimension of the div-father and so I can't change the chart size.

I have this simple HTML

```html
<div style="height: 300px; width: 500px">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
</div>
```

and here's my js

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = 100,
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin
```

but i read that `attr("width")` and `attr("height")` both return a string so the value should be "100%". What can i do to have the real dimension based on how the div change his size?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`svg.node().getBoundingClientRect()` to get the actual width and height values.

To get the width and height specifically, for example, you would use:

```
var clientRect = svc.node().getBoundingClientRect()
var width = clientRect.width
var height = clientRect.height
```

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990857/d3-js-how-to-get-the-computed-width-and-height-for-an-arbitrary-element) which is similar

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get the answer linked. What should the function return?

Comment: I edited the answer to hopefully be a little clearer